# Centos 6, local yum repo, and multiple versions of the same rpm

Tags: yum, centos6

I'm trying to set up a really simple local repo. I want to have a basic repo with two versions of only one rpm, so I did:

```
mkdir /packages/x64
```

copy two rpms to /packages/x64

```
[root@repo x64]# createrepo --verbose /packages/x64
1/2 - jre-6u37-linux-amd64.rpm
2/2 - jre-7u9-linux-x64.rpm
```

Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata

Added the repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo

But when I do:

```
[root@repo x64]# yum list jre
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
jre.x86_64  1.7.0_09-fcs  local
```

ie it only shows the latest version. I know that they're both in the repo because I've run this:

```
[root@repo x64]# rpm -qp jre-6u37-linux-amd64.rpm
jre-1.6.0_37-fcs.x86_64
[root@repo x64]# rpm -qp jre-7u9-linux-x64.rpm 
jre-1.7.0_09-fcs.x86_64
```

and when I remove the latter version, and run createrepo again, the former shows up. Most puzzling, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is:

```
yum --showduplicates list jre
```

That should give you a list of priors.

```
yum list kernel

Available Packages
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.14.1.el6                                         updates
```

And...

```
yum --showduplicates list kernel

Available Packages
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.el6                                              base                                    
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.1.1.el6                                          updates                                 
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.2.1.el6                                          updates                                 
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.5.1.el6                                          updates                                 
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.5.2.el6                                          updates                                 
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.9.1.el6                                          updates                                 
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.11.1.el6                                         updates                                 
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.14.1.el6                                         updates
```

By default, yum won't show you ALL available packages. As far as it's concerned, the `jre` package has two versions, of which 1.7.0 is the newest so that's all it shows without being told.